# jQuery viewer coordinates onZoom

Tags: jquery, zooming

I have been using the [jQuery iviewer plugin](https://github.com/can3p/iviewer) to do some image manipulation. I am able to save the `zoom/location` state of an image using the `onClick(ev, point)` event handler. The handler returns the coordinates of where the user click. From this, I can store the coordinates and the zoom level that the user has selected. I am calling the following:

```
$('#image-container').iviewer('set_zoom', zoom, false, coords);
```

This will zoom in and move to the correct location that the user has saved.

Now, I am trying to perform a similar action if the user zooms into the image using the mouse scroll. The `afterZoom(zoom)` method only returns the zoom level. I am trying to save the state of the image using the zoom level and coordinates. I noticed in the code that if you call

```
coords = $('#image-container').iviewer('info', 'coords');
```

This returns coordinates at any given time. However, the coordinates returned are negative values. Why are they negative? I can't seem to figure how to translate these coordinates into proper values so that I can move and zoom the image to the place that the user has saved.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution than using this library. Decided to use OpenLayers to provide zoom/pan capabilities.